# NSDictionary becomes NSCFString when I save to NSUserDefaults in Swift

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

NSDictionary becomes NSCFString when I save to NSUserDefaults:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var questionforsave: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var answerforsave: UITextField!

    var answersSaved = [String:String]()

    @IBAction func savePressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        if questionforsave.text.isEmpty || answerforsave.text.isEmpty{

            let alert = UIAlertView()
            alert.title = "Empty fields"
            alert.message = "Please Enter Text In Both Text Fields"
            alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
            alert.show()
        }else{

            println("is ok")
            var answerSave = answerforsave.text
            var questionSave = questionforsave.text


            answersSaved[questionSave] = answerSave

            let alert = UIAlertView()
            alert.title = "Success!"
            alert.message = "It worked!"
            alert.addButtonWithTitle("Awesome!")
            alert.show()

            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(answersSaved, forKey: "answersSaved")
            println(answersSaved)


        }


    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        println(answersSaved)



        if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("answersSaved") != nil {
            answersSaved = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("answersSaved") as! [String:String]

        }else{
            println("No Defaults")
        }




    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {
        //do the stuff here
        resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }


}
```

Comment: You should include your code

Comment: `println()` answersSaved and questionSave and add to the question. Also you should not be using `NSUserDefaults` as a data model.

Comment: you have not even saved any `NSDictionary` here, I hope you have realised it already; you are saving a static string (`"answersSaved"`) for the key `"answersSaved"`.

Comment: Yes, I'll correct the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are setting a string and then trying to retrieve a dictionary, but I would recommend using `if let` to retrieve the dictionary and then optionally cast it to be `[String: String]`:

```
var answersSaved = [String: String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let answersFromDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryForKey("answersSaved") as? [String: String] {
        answersSaved = answersFromDefaults
    } else {
        // Failed to retrieve value from NSUserDefaults
    }

    answersSaved = ["test": "a"] // Set answersSaved somewhere in your code
}

@IBAction func saveButtonPressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(answersSaved, forKey: "answersSaved")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("answersSaved", forKey: "answersSaved")
```

You're writing the string `"answersSaved"` into `NSUserDefaults`. I assume you meant `answersSaved`.

Comment: I tried without the quotes but the app also crashed

Comment: try  var answersSaved: [String:String] = [ ]

Comment: "app also crashed" is not helpful (and is likely a different bug). You need to indicate exactly what is happening and at what line.  The use of `as!` means "if this isn't exactly correct, please crash." You would never want that when reading from an external source like user defaults. It may not even be set in user defaults.

Answer (score 1):

> You should cast it optionally as a [String:String] dictionary.

Try this:

```
if let answersFromDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryForKey("answersSaved") as?      [String: String] {
    answersSaved = answersFromDefaults
} else {
    // Failed to retrieve value from NSUserDefaults
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When you load the dictionary into NSUserDefaults you should do it like this:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(answersSaved, forKey: "answersSaved")
```

This saves it as a generic NSObject. When you want to read out the data though use the command:

```
answersSaved = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryForKey("answersSaved")
```

This should specify that the object is a Dictionary

Comment: Nope, I got a 'Bad Instruction' crash